# How to change Toolbar Navigation and Overflow Menu icons (appcompat v7)?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I am having a hard time with v7 Toolbar. What was once a simple task for `ActionBar`, now seems overly complex. No matter what style I set, I cannot change either navigation icon (which opens a Drawer) or overflow menu icon (which opens a menu).

So I have a `Toolbar`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ghex"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    >
```

I code it looks like this

```
//before in the code I do
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

private void initToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Now, I need to change the `Drawable` for those two icons.

[image]

How do I do this for compat v7 `Toolbar`? I guess I would need to change the arrow visible when the drawer is open (Android 5.0).

Answer (score 137, accepted):

To change the **navigation icon** you can use:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

To change the **overflow icon** you can use the method:

```
toolbar.setOverflowIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_my_menu);
```

If you would like to **change the color** of the icons you can use:

with a **Material Components Theme** (with a `MaterialToolbar` for example):

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"
    ...>

  <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <!-- color used by navigation icon and overflow icon -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/myColor</item>
  </style>
```

---

With an **AppCompat Theme**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar" />


<style name="ThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

   <!-- navigation icon color -->
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_color</item>

    <!-- color of the menu overflow icon -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

---

You can also change the overflow icon overriding in the app theme the **`actionOverflowButtonStyle`** attribute:

With a Material Components Theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="srcCompat">@drawable/my_overflow_menu</item>
</style>
```

With an AppCompat theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="srcCompat">@drawable/my_overflow_menu</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I only what to change the color of those items. Can I do it without changing drawables?

Comment: I tried `setNavigationIcon` from the code already, but it does not change the icon. Do I have to make any reference in the toolbar XML, a reference to  the Style? Or I simply set the style of the complete app in the Manifest file and the re-style it as you suggested?

Comment: @sandalone you can change the color without changing the drawables. Just updated the answer

Comment: Can I use the first style example somehow to change only the oveflow menu color without affecting the rest of the toolbar components?

Comment: How would you change the color of the overflow button at runtime?

Comment: How do you know that android:textColorSecondary controls the menu overflow icon? And only the menu overflow icon? I'm really hoping for a document.

Comment: If you've added activity through Android studio, please check styles and local widget attributes as for color and theme changes first.

Answer (score 26):

```
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
mToolbar.setOverflowIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_menu));
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Because none of the answers related to modifying the themes and styles worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

For right menu you can do it:

```
public static Drawable setTintDrawable(Drawable drawable, @ColorInt int color) {
            drawable.clearColorFilter();
            drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            drawable.invalidateSelf();
            Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable).mutate();
            DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, color);
            return wrapDrawable;
        }
```

> And in your activity

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_profile, menu);
        Drawable send = menu.findItem(R.id.send);
        Drawable msg = menu.findItem(R.id.message);
        DrawableUtils.setTintDrawable(send.getIcon(), Color.WHITE);
        DrawableUtils.setTintDrawable(msg.getIcon(), Color.WHITE);
        return true;
    }
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: If you are using a vector you can do `android:tint="YOUR COLOR"` as they did [here](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88)

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple, easy and better approach, if we need to change only the color of hamburger/back icon.

It is better as it changes color only of desired icon, whereas `colorControlNormal` and `android:textColorSecondary` might affect other childviews of toolbar as well.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hey Sachin, this worked wonderfully. Could you provide some references in the android documentation so that I can learn more about theming other widgets ?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to change your icons to a **Vector** , create a new one.
and then in your `Activity.java` :

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
mToolbar.setOverflowIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_icon2));
```

To change **Vector** icon Color, go to your **Vector XML file**.. in this case it will be `your_icon.xml`, it will look like this :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="@color/Your_Color"
    android:pathData="M15.41,7.41L14,6l-6,6 6,6 1.41,-1.41L10.83,12z"/>
```

Note that we used these attributes to set the Vector's color :

```
android:fillColor="@color/Your_Color"
```

**Edit** : You can't use a color from your colors.XML or somewhere else , the color must be decalred directly in the Vector's XML file.. so it will look like this :

```
android:fillColor="#FFF"
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change menu item icons, arrow icon (back/up), and 3 dots icon you can use `android:tint`

```
  <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/your_color</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above solutions worked for me in API 21 or greater, but did not in API 19 (KitKat). Making a small change did the trick for me in the earlier versions. Notice `Widget.Holo` instead of `Widget.AppCompat`

```
<style name="OverFlowStyle"    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_overflow</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

add your default theme this line;

```
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_color</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

which theme you have used in activity add below one line code

for white

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:tint">#ffffff</item>
  </style>

or 
 <style name="AppThemeName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:tint">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

for black

```
   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:tint">#000000</item>
  </style>

or 
 <style name="AppThemeName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:tint">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change color for options menu items you can

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu)

    menu?.forEach {
        it.icon.setTint(Color.your_color)
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin

```
setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarParcels.toolbar)
```

val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView

```
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_parcels)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    //close navigation drawer on navigation menu item listener
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        if (item.itemId == R.id.closeDrawer) {
            onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
        } else {
            onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
        }
        false
    })
```

TO change the tool bar icon

```
supportActionBar!!.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer_icon_default)
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to show the icon, use `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.xxx.xxx)`

In my case the code is:-

`getSupportActionBar().setIcon (R.mipmap.ic_launcher);`