# Toolbar sets the wrong icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

In my application I want to set a custom menu for the toolbar. The icon that I defined in the `menu_settings.xml` is an arrow, but when I start the application, it's a three-point menu instead of the arrow (as seen in the Pictures). After hours of research I still can't figure out why it loads this icon instead of the arrow (yes I checked the drawable ;) ). Thank you for solutions and hints!

[image: False Icon 1]
[image: False icon after click on three-point menu]

SettingsActivity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDelegate().installViewFactory();
    getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    boolean hasConfiguredSettings = intent.getBooleanExtra(HAS_CONFIGURED_SETTINGS, false);

    if (hasConfiguredSettings) {
        toolbar.setTitle("Wähle deine Linien!");


    } else {
        // Back button in Toolbar
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
}

private void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar) {
    getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
    if (mDelegate == null) {
        mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
    }
    return mDelegate;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    boolean hasConfiguredSettings = intent.getBooleanExtra("HAS_CONFIGURED_SETTINGS", false);
    if (hasConfiguredSettings) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

menu_settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".SettingsActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_checked"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:title="@string/configuration_action_button"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_right"/>
</menu>
```

toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/primary"
/>
```

The toolbar is included with:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Comment: Yes. The true icon is: `ic_action_arrow_right` which looks like this: [http://www.icons4android.com/icon/1126](http://www.icons4android.com/icon/1126)

Comment: The false icon looks like the icon in the picures, on the right side of the toolbar. It actually looks like this: [http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/205d/index.htm](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/205d/index.htm) ... it's the so called Kebab menu ;)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein He meant wrong/correct icon, but chose wrong words.

Comment: I see. Possibly the right and the wrong icons are named inversely. Therefore, Android `seems` to swap them.

Comment: Sorry I m not a native Speaker. Changed the title of the question ;)
No the names of the icons are correct.

Comment: Try removing ´android:orderInCategory="101"´

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't had any impact on the icon.

Comment: The problem is that menu item is shown in popup (like this: http://www.techotopia.com/images/8/87/Kindle_fire_overflow_action_toolbar.png ), so it can't have icon. Oveflow icon(three dots) can't be changed as far as I know. `app:showAsAction="always"` make it look as you want, but it isn't for some reason.  Maybe try with `android:showAsAction="always"` (`android` instead of `app` prefix)

Comment: Check out this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038861/how-to-change-toolbar-navigation-and-overflow-menu-icons-appcompat-v7

Comment: @skra As I use AppCompat this doesn't work.

Comment: @KNeerajLal yes this changes the button, thank you! Now I just need just to disable the popup with "Weiter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [AppCompatDelegate#getMenuInflater](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html#getMenuInflater()) instead of [Activity#getMenuInflater()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getMenuInflater()).

Replace the below line:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
```

with

```
MenuInflater inflater = getDelegate().getMenuInflater();
```