# customize the overflow icon of ToolBar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 ...
```

I would like to use my own icon for the overflow icon showing on the right side of the toolbar. So, I tried:

```
    // I am using ButterKnife library to bind views
    @BindView(R.id.my_toolbar)
    Toolbar mToolBar;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);

            // use my_icon.png for overflow icon of toolbar 
       mToolBar.setOverflowIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_icon));
        }
```

When I run my app, there is no overflow icon showing.... Why?

How to customize overflow icon of ToolBar?

Comment: `android:layout_width="0dp"` Give it some width...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038861/how-to-change-toolbar-navigation-and-overflow-menu-icons-appcompat-v7

Comment: I am using ConstraintLayout, this is what constriant layout gives... I should only care about the margin to border.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Toolbar Navigation and Overflow Menu icons (appcompat v7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038861/how-to-change-toolbar-navigation-and-overflow-menu-icons-appcompat-v7)