# How to change the navigation icon color

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, android-styles, android-navigationview

I have a navigationView in my app and after add two lines in app style :

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

The Navigation icon color changed to black and for this problem i added this line in style :

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
```

Now navigation icon is white again but now i have a new problem . With above code , the title of navigation items is change color too.

I didn't find a solution to this Interference

**Style :**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>

</style>
```

**Navigation Menu :**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group
        android:id="@+id/testGRP"
        android:checkableBehavior="single"
        >
    <item android:title="جلسه : انتخاب نشده"
        android:id="@+id/menuItem_StudentList11"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up"
        />

    <item android:title="مرتب سازی"
        android:id="@+id/menuItem_StudentList_Quize1"
        android:icon="@drawable/all_exam_icon"
        />

        <item android:title="@string/Navigation_StudentList3"
            android:id="@+id/menuItem_StudentList_Quize"
            android:icon="@drawable/all_exam_icon"
            />

    </group>


    <item android:title="رویدادها:"> //this line is title

    <menu>

    <item android:title="@string/Navigation_StudentList4"
        android:id="@+id/menuItem_StudentList_MidTerm"
        android:icon="@drawable/all_exam_icon"
        />

    <item android:title="@string/Navigation_StudentList5"
        android:id="@+id/menuItem_StudentList_EndTerm"
        android:icon="@drawable/all_exam_icon"
        />

    <item android:title="امتحان عملی"
        android:id="@+id/menuItem_StudentList_Practical"
        android:icon="@drawable/all_exam_icon"
        />


    <item android:title="@string/Navigation_StudentList6"
        android:id="@+id/menuItem_StudentList_Project"
        android:icon="@drawable/all_projcet_icon"
        />


    <item android:title="@string/Navigation_StudentList2"
        android:id="@+id/menuItem_StudentList_Conference"
        android:icon="@drawable/all_conference_icon"
        />
    </menu>
        </item>


    <item android:title="@string/Navigation_StudentList1"
        android:id="@+id/menuItem_StudentList1"
        android:icon="@drawable/all_notifiicon_icon"
        />

    <item android:title="@string/Navigation_StudentList7"
        android:id="@+id/menuItem_StudentList7"
        android:icon="@drawable/main_newclass_icon"
        />
</menu>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Oox.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prrJp.jpg)

Comment: Are you using a toolbar in your layout?

Comment: Yes i use toolbar

Comment: Its already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29040409/9882579) refer this answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using a `Toolbar`, to change the navigation icon color you can use:

With a [**`MaterialToolbar`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) or (androidx and a Material theme):

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"
    ...>

  <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <!-- color used by navigation icon and overflow icon -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/secondaryColor</item>
  </style>
```

With the support Library:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  app:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar" />


<style name="ThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <!-- navigation icon color -->
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to change text colors/appearance in the `NavigationView` Items, you should use the attribs

- `app:itemTextColor`
- `app:itemIconTint`
- `app:itemTextAppearance`

Otherwise, Specify which view's color you want to change. Setting `android:textColorSeconday` is a bad idea according to me.

Comment: My problem is the color of the navigationView icon, not the items and i don't find another way to change it

Comment: Ok I get it now, That's the overflow icon, but not the navigationView icon

Comment: This will be changed by setting toolbar theme