# How can I change android Toolbar home icon

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, toolbar, titlebar

I trying to change the toolbar icons like
[Image 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pox3w.jpg)
to
[Image 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4rZJ.jpg)
and similarly the back icon.

I am able to change the default icons color using

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/whit</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/whit</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/IconStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="IconStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/name_heading</item>
</style>
```

I already try:

```
toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolBarId);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_right_select);
```

but now work.
Is there any way to solve it from the 
 ***styles.xml***
file?

Comment: Use the Toolbar API. `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(...)`

Comment: what do you mean by 'home icon'? and Are you implementing it in activity or fragment?

Comment: please go throug this link you will get expected answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29038861/how-to-change-toolbar-navigation-and-overflow-menu-icons-appcompat-v7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_right_select);
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin:

```
supportActionBar!!.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back)
```